# Discord Bot Image Scraper using Praw - Error

Tags: python, image, web-scraping, discord, praw

I am trying to write a bot that generates a random picture of a horse from r/horses upon a given command. I have somehow reached a dead end - my code seems to be intact but it will not generate my horse picture in my server. I'm not sure why! Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
from typing import Any, Iterator

TOKEN = 'token'

from discord.ext import commands
import random
import praw


client = commands.Bot(description="horse", command_prefix=None)
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='id',
                     client_secret='secret',
                     user_agent='horse bot')
@client.command()
async def horse(ctx):
    horses_submissions = reddit.subreddit('horses').hot(limit=100)
    horses_submissions = [x for x in horses_submissions if not x.stickied]
    submission = random.choice(horses_submissions)
    await ctx.send(submission.url)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('the ranch! the ranch! {0.user} has joined the ranch!'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    username = str(message.author).split('#')[0]
    user_message = str(message.content)
    channel = str(message.channel.name)
    print(f'{username}: {user_message} ({channel})')

    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.channel.name == 'the-ranch':
        if user_message.lower() == 'hello':
            await message.channel.send(f'greetings {username}! give me oats')
            return
        elif user_message.lower() == 'bye':
            await message.channel.send(f'please bring oats when you return, {username}..')
            return
        elif user_message.lower() == "!random":
            response = f' Here, have a random number, (as a treat): {random.randrange(1000000)}'
            await message.channel.send(response)
            return

    if user_message.lower() == '!anywhere':
        await message.channel.send('hey i am here too')

    #pics
    if message.content.startswith('horse'):
        horses = await horse()
        await message.channel.send(horses)


client.run(TOKEN)
```

and here are the errors I recieve:

```
C:\Users\17734\bot\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/17734/bot/main.py
the ranch! the ranch! horse bot#5576 has joined the ranch!
aggie: horse (the-ranch)
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\17734\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\17734\bot\main.py", line 51, in on_message
    horses = await horse()
  File "C:\Users\17734\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 374, in __call__
    return await self.callback(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: horse() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'
```

thanks for your help!

LAST EDITED 10/26/21 5:11 PM CST

Answer (score 0):

First of all, consider using `async praw`, it i's recommend for using it with Discord bots. Refer to https://asyncpraw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ so you can learn about it.

The problem may be that you are getting a random number between 1 and 1000 but you are only receiving back from Reddit API the first 100 hot images. Try putting a `print('index: {i}'.format(i=i))` before line 17 so you can debug your code and see if it's a `Index Out Of Range`  error.